# Angular detecting li elements order changes

Tags: angularjs, html-framework-7

I'm working with Framework7 (http://framework7.io/) and with Angular. 
In my case, I have a sortable list (from F7) filled with an **ng-repeat** directive.

My problem is when I update my list (LI elements), the $scope array does not change its order.

What I expect is that when I make changes on the list, the $scope array which filled the list, also changes the order of its elements.

How I can obtain the expected behaviour?

I think that with JS/jQuery I can find a workaround, but I want to know which could be a correct solution with Angular.

Many thanks!

Comment: how the list been updated?

Comment: Dragging manually the LI elements (allowed by F7). The right order is defined by the order of the LI items on the HTML code.

Comment: maybe the dragging event didn't trigger Angular internal digesting, try to add an angular directive on that dragging handler, and in directive, call `$scope.$apply` or whatever  angular methods could trigger digesting.

Comment: If I try to call $apply or $digest from console, the array is not updated. Will it works with a directive?